# Is it possible to save level progress within a campaign in Brofoce?

Tags: broforce

Arcade mode in Broforce automatically saves my progress when I return to the menu (although I always have to play the level that I just completed one more time). Is there any way to save the levels that were just completed in campaign mode? I finished around five levels in Campaign 15 when my hand started to hurt, and after returning to the menu, the campaign reset from the beginning and my save was back at 91% completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I don't see any way to continue from where you left off, I think its designed this way so you have to complete the levels together not just restart the boss fight.